# How to get great looking transparent PNGs on BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, png, transparent

I am able to use PNGs that have drop shadows but the effect when displayed on the BlackBerry looks like it collapses the transparent channel down from its original smooth gradient to only several transparent values giving it a choppy look.

The same issue is encountered by drawing on the UI using BlackBerry fields or the graphics.drawBitmap method.  Anyone want to share hints for getting great looking transparent effects on the BlackBerry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dither your images or pre-composite them.  When loading an image on a BlackBerry, you get at most 4 bits of alpha data, which allows 4 bits each for RGB.  So, if you want to dither your transparent images, go for RGB4444.  If you don't dither them, that's what causes 8-bit alpha to just be mapped to the nearest 4-bit value.

If you include no alpha data (i.e., precomposite), you can get RGB565, which will have a better image quality overall, but you will have to deal with static positioning for your dropshadows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Pre-compositing sounds good isn't yet an option so I'll start by looking to making the best of the 16 values of transparency.